# How to make my program not add a repeat to my list? Python

Tags: python

I need my python program to not add the same letter in the list. There can be no repeats. This is my current code:

```
common = []
for letter in first and last:
  if letter  in first and last:
    common.append(letter)
print common
```

EDIT: Ok I did this and it seems to work.

```
for letter in first and last:
    if letter  in first and last and not common:
```

EDIT: Sorry It has to be done with "LISTS"

Comment: Is this 3.0?  In 2.6, the keyword `and` produces the logical and, that is, if either list is empty, it returns the first empty list, otherwise, it returns the second list.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't understand verbal logic. Tell the interpreter *exactly* what you mean:

```
if (letter in first) and (letter in last) and (letter not in common):
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the list to be in the same order that you read it in? One approach is to first make a set object, add everything to the set, then make the list by iterating over the set, appending each item in the set to the list. If you do a lookup on a list that will take O(n) time (n = size of list) whereas the set object will take O(1) time.

I think something like this will work for you. Quick question, what are first and last? And why do you check "if letter in first and last" -- one cannot iterate over two lists in one for loop. If you want to do something *like* this, then first zip the lists together (zip(list1, list2)) to create a list of tuples, then iterate over this zipped list.

It seems like you want to do something like this.

```
    # thank you user NullUserException
    common = list(set([letter for letter in listOfStuff]))
```

EDIT -- Okay, then settle for the O(n) lookup time.

```
    common = []
    for letter in listOfStuff:
      # if statement stolen from user Blender =D
      if (letter in first) and (letter in last) and (letter not in common):
        common.append(letter)
    print common
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use sets for this hw problem. But thanks.

Comment: Why do that if you can just do: `mylist = list(myset)`?